# Insertion sort in Ruby gives undefined method error

Tags: ruby, insertion-sort

I am working on learning algorithms and trying to implement Insertion Sort in Ruby.
My code:

```
  b = [15, 23, 1, 17, 99, 68];
   c=[];  
   for j in 2..b.size do
    klucz = b[j];
    c<<b[j];
    i=j-1;
    while i > 0 && c[i] > klucz do
      c[i+1]=c[i];
      i=i-1;
      c[i+1]=key;
    end
    return c;
   end
```

When I try to run code, I get this error

```
`block in <main>': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Anybody got any idea?

Comment: I've never seen such implementation for Insertion sort in any language. BTW, for the first time/loop, `i` will be 1 and so `c[i]` will be `nil` as it will have only 1 element indexed as 0. Hence the error at `c[i] > klucz`.

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from this line:

`while i > 0 && c[i] > klucz do`

Consider the first execution of the `for j in 2..b.size do` loop:

- j is assigned a value of 2
- c gets the b[2] appended to its array. c is now [1]
- i is assigned a value of j - 1, aka 1

Now on the `while i > 0 && c[i] > klucz do` line, c only has one element, but you're trying to reference `c[i]`, which is `c[1]`. `c[1]` references the *second* element of the array since arrays are zero based in ruby. So `c[1]` is nil, and can't be used with the greater than comparison operator.